# ResourceExhausted: 429 Quota exceeded for quota metric Natural Language API through Dataflow using Python SDK

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building Dataflow pipleline to read fro CSV , perform Sentiment analysis through Google Cloud NLP API and send teh result to BigQuery.

when the function that perform sentiment analysis get the pcollection is gives me the above mentioned error.

What I am thinking about is splitting the Pcollection into small Pcollection in order handle Quote limitation in NLP API.

```
(p
       | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(src_path)
       | 'ParseCSV' >> beam.ParDo(Analysis())
       | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> ...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have auto-scaling turned on as it is on by default.  Try turning it off and then setting the working count limit to something small like 5. This will provide a cap to the number of underlying worker threads processing the bundles. From there you can play around with instance type (number of cores) in order to maximize your throughput.

The default limit is 600 requests per minute which is pretty low. You can also request a quota increase for NLP. My advice is to do both fixed pool to throttle and then ramp up quota to dial in your wall clock time goal.

Comment: thanks for your Note it really help me put to figure the problem. for now I have added "time.sleep" to slow down process requests to NLP Api